# how to eliminate checking of alphanumeric character from middle of string python regex

Tags: python, regex

---

I want to eliminate "CC1009" and need to check remaining which include.
"ABC" "Tx" "XYZ" "20200506"(date) .*
This 4 value is mendatory

So inshort from this text
'ABCTxXYZCC100920200506050003.xml' = 'ABCTxXYZ CC1009 20200506050003.xml'
i want my expression should dont check anything like this - CC1009
after XYZ and before 20200506 (date)

This value CC1009 is dynamic it is available in some file and also not available in some file also length is not defined.
Please help me accordingly

I tried in below code but it is not working (python regex)

```
import re

file_name = 'ABCTxXYZCC100920200506050003.xml'
Split Example = 'ABC  Tx  XYZ  CC1009  20200506  050003.xml'
 
RegexPattern = re.compile(r'^(ABC|CDE)+(Tx|Fm)+(XYZ)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*)+([0-9]{4})+(0[1-9]|1[012])+(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])+(.+)$')
pattern_check = RegexPattern.match(file_name)

if pattern_check:
    print('Match')
else:
    print('No Match')
```

Comment: Remove the `+` after the capturing groups and make the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]*?` non greedy `^(ABC|CDE)+(Tx|Fm)+(XYZ)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)([0-9]{4})(0[1-9]|1[012])+(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])+(.+)$`  https://regex101.com/r/5hkqkY/1

Comment: if other elements are mandatory and have constant size then you can slice them - ie `file_name[8:-18]`

Comment: size is not constant and yes other element is mandatory. can we skip middke part anyhow? and check remaining which is date?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all the `+` characters after the capturing groups. As `CC1009`  is dynamic, you can use the character class and make it non greedy `[a-zA-Z0-9]*?` to prevent matching too much digits.

If you want the date to be a whole group, you can create a single capturing group and use a non capturing group `(?:` inside it for the month and day parts.

```
^(ABC|CDE)(Tx|Fm)(XYZ)([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)([0-9]{4}(?:0[1-9]|1[012])(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))(.+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MeEdsZ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zFL3ji)

*Example code*

```
import re

file_name = 'ABCTxXYZCC100920200506050003.xml'
RegexPattern = re.compile(r'^(ABC|CDE)(Tx|Fm)(XYZ)([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)([0-9]{4}(?:0[1-9]|1[012])(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))(.+)$')
pattern_check = RegexPattern.match(file_name)

if pattern_check:
    print('Match')
else:
    print('No Match')
    
print(re.findall(RegexPattern, file_name))
print(re.findall(RegexPattern, "ABCTxXYZ20200506050003.xml"))
```

*Output*

```
Match
[('ABC', 'Tx', 'XYZ', 'CC1009', '20200506', '050003.xml')]
[('ABC', 'Tx', 'XYZ', '', '20200506', '050003.xml')]
```

Comment: After changing file name it is not working. I just changed month with 22 instead 05 but it is showing me match.  New File : ABCTxXYZCC100920202206050003.xml I added 22 after yyyy to check whether date pattern work or not but it is not working.

Comment: Are the any more specifics? Matching the date format has options using the alternations and the following `.+` also has options to fit in the date match.

Comment: matching date is mandatory and after date there will be some charavter which we do not need to check.. again it can be anything in numeric.

Comment: Hi The Fourth Bird, Do let me know if you have any idea to check date in yyyymmdd in same code provided by you.

Comment: @shaikhakbar Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/8ob43f/1

Comment: I tried with this 'ABCTxXYZCC100920202206050003.xml' but month is 22 which is incorrect and no match but code says match.

Comment: @shaikhakbar That is because the pattern will look for a match for the date pattern. And it can find it, as what comes before and after the date in the string are also digits. That is why I asked if there are more details or rules, because the pattern can not determine that the date part starts after `CC1009` as you say that it is dynamic and sometimes not there. is `CC1009` always CC and 4 digits?

Comment: Yes, That string is dynamic.. I tried some changes in your expression and it is working.

Comment: I request you to just validate: ^(ABC|CDE)(Tx|Fm)(XYZ)[a-zA-Z0-9]*?((?:2020|2021|2022|2023|2024|2025)(?:0[1-9]|1[012])(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))(.+)$

Comment: @shaikhakbar You made the year part a bit more specific, you might shorten it like this https://regex101.com/r/t6bWHA/1 It has the same matches as the previous pattern I commented.